# Changing scale in Y-Axis

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using chart in my C# form. I have action that updates values in that chart, but if values get maximum value they move out grinds. 
How can I change maximum value at Y-Axis? Below is how I update values.

```
int[] TempScore= new int[100];
for (int i = 0; i < ScoreChart.Series["Players"].Points.Count(); i++)
{
    TempScore[i] = Convert.ToInt32(ScoreChart.Series["Players"].Points[i].YValues[0]);
    ScoreChart.Series["Players"].Points[i].YValues[0]+=PlayersScore;
}
ScoreChart.Series.Clear();
ScoreChart.Series.Add("Players");
for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(NumberOfPlayer.Text); i++)
{
    ScoreChart.Series["Players"].Points.Add(0).Label = "Gracz " + i;
    ScoreChart.Series["Players"].Points[i].YValues[0] = TempScore[i] + 1;
}
```

Comment: @rdkleine I think you asking about that `using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;` If I'm worng please correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Chart in .NET 4.0, you can set the Y maximum like this:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 10;
```